# How to force an NSWindow to be opened on the Desktop only?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, window

I have a status bar app that has some windows but if i'm on fullscreen in an app the window is opened in front of it. How can i force the window to be opened on the Desktop and move the user to the desktop?
I seek something that happens in Twitter.app: when you try to make a new tweet using the status bar button "New Tweet..." and the new tweet window is opened on the Desktop.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0):

Try [NSApplicationPresentationOptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/currentSystemPresentationOptions). All You Have to do is set `currentSystemPresentationOptions`

Comment: can you write an example on how to implement it, please?

Comment: Check the link to see the apple documentation then go from there